# Missing or insufficient permissions on Datastore REST API access

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-apis-explorer

I have manually created entity in Datastore and trying to access it from the test page https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery.
It works for myself and returns proper entity, but for another users it returns error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
                {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
                    "detail": "/Datastore.RunQuery to [2002:a17:908:2348::]:4133 : APP_ERROR(6) Missing or insufficient permissions."
 }
 ]
 }
}
```

How can I grant permission to other users?